# VBA object required error with Range function

Tags: excel, vba, debugging

I have a piece of VBA code that looks up value from another excel to create a True/False flag and based on the flag, I have set two different char values. I get 'object required' error in the following code. Can some one please explain why?

```
Sub test()

  Dim part1 As String
  Dim part2 As String
  Dim a As Range

  part1 = "=ifna(INDEX('DRG and Zip Summaries'!$A$10:$A$58,MATCH('DRG Summary Target'!F2 ""x_x_x"""
  part2 = ",'DRG and Zip Summaries'!$C$10:$C$58,0)),'FALSE')"

With Range("A2:A183").FormulaArray = part1
                                  .Replace """x_x_x""", part2
End With

For Each a In Range("A2:A183")
 If a.Value = "FALSE" Then
        Range("B" & a.rownum) = Chr(168)
 Else:  Range("B" & a.rownum) = Chr(254)
 End If
Next

 End Sub
```

Comment: Which line gives you an error? `Range("B" & a.rownum)` is incorrect, it should be `Range("B" & a.Row)`. Also, you should qualify your referecnes, for instance `Workbooks("Workbook Name").Sheets("Sheet Name").Range("A2:A183")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't place your formula in the WITH declaration. The WITH declaration is just supposed to identify the object to work with, not make any changes like putting values in it. Use:

```
With Range("A2:A183")
    .FormulaArray = part1
...
```

etc.

I'm not sure why you're using the "part1" and "part2" structure either. If it's just because the formula was getting too long, you can break lines using an underscore character, thus:

```
formula=""=ifna(INDEX('DRG and Zip Summaries'!$A$10:$A$58," & _
    "MATCH('DRG Summary Target'!F2",'DRG and Zip Summaries'!" & _
    "$C$10:$C$58,0)),'FALSE')"
```

The underscore will ensure these three lines are all processed as a single line.

Comment: I removed the 'with' section and used the code as suggested with & _ . The error now says 'Application defined or object defined error'

Comment: There was a glitch in my formula, with the double-quotes before the =. It should be
    formula="=ifna(Index( .... etc.

Also, make sure you're closing the " at the end of each line and including the &, then reopening the " at the beginning of the next line.

Comment: Yep, I had noted that and wrote the formula accordingly so it looks like following code:   
   
                Sheet("Sheet5").Range("A2:A183").FormulaArray =         
"=ifna(INDEX('DRG and Zip Summaries'!$A$10:$A$58," & _
 "MATCH('DRG Summary Target'!F2,'DRG and Zip Summaries'!" & _                                   
"$C$10:$C$58,0)),'FALSE')"

Comment: Use double-quotes around "False" at the end, or remove the single quotes. Excel doesn't know what to do with 'FALSE', which is where the error is probably coming from.